# How to specify font-family for individual select.option elements in jquery mobile?

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

A typical jQuery mobile custom select menu is coded like this:

```
<div class="ui-field-contain">
    <select id="mymenu" data-native-menu="false">
        <option data-placeholder="true">Choose one...</option>
        <option value="1">The 1st Option</option>
        <option value="2">The 2nd Option</option>
        <option value="3">The 3rd Option</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

The framework then turns that into this:

```
<ul id="mymenu-listbox" class="ui-selectmenu-list ui-listview">
   <li class="" data-option-index="1" data-icon="false" role="option" aria-selected="false">
        <a class="ui-btn" href="#">The first option</a>
<!--et cetera-->
```

I'm trying to create a select menu where the user selects a custom font-family. Obviously, I'd like to be able to visualise each option in the list, but inline styling the `<option>` tags isn't working. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can't you just put the styles in a stylesheet? `#mymenu :first-child` and so on?

Comment: Thanks, I thought that was a great idea and tried it, but got thwarted by the framework. See edit.

Comment: Hm, no unique combination of classes or other attributes? Can you provide an example of what the actual generated source looks like? (In Mozilla, bring up the menu, select all and choose "View selection source" from the right click menu will show the HTML after all processing has been dong to it.)

Comment: I'm an idiot. In trying to play around with your solution, I accidentally replicated the same id for several divs and that caused the framework to start making up its own id names. The following is tested working css: if you paste that as an answer I'll gladly accept it. `/*note first child is invisible background screen*/ #mymenu-listbox > ul > li:nth-child(2 /*3,4,etc*/) > a {
  font-family: Georgia, serif; } 
`

Comment: If you figured out the solution yourself, you can post it as an answer!

Answer (score 0):

With help from @Mr Lister, the following sass works:

```
/*first child is an invisible screen*/
#text-font-list-listbox, #heading-font-list-listbox > ul >
  li:nth-child(2) > a
    font-family: Georgia,serif
  li:nth-child(3) > a
    font-family: Palatino,serif
  li:nth-child(4) > a
    font-family: Times,serif
  /*etc*/
```